# Action button with modals and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a problem in my codes. So the idea is I have two modals that triggered when user Click OK or Fail

So when the user click ok the modal is

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                    This is the confirmation window to PASS all the Quality Control for, <br/><br/>
                    Project : <b>'.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].'</b><br/>
                    HeadMark : <b>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</b><br/>
                    ID : <b>'.$row['ID'].'</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" name="acceptButton" id="acceptButton" class="btn btn-success">Confirm PASS!</button>
```

and when user click FAIL its still the same body but with different button action,

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" name="rejectButton" id="rejectButton" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm REJECT!</button>
                  </div>
```

and my jQuery corresponded with those buttons are,

```
 $('#acceptButton').click(function() {
            var myData = $('#data_field');
            $.post("acceptClass.php",{
            acceptProjectName : myData.attr("data_project"), 
            acceptHeadMark : myData.attr("data_headmark"),
            acceptId : myData.attr("data_id")
            },function callback(result){
                window.location = "update_fabrication_qc_pass.php";
            });
        });

        $('#rejectButton').click(function() {
                var myData = $('#data_field');
                $.post("rejectClass.php",{
                projectName : myData.attr("data_project"), 
                headMark : myData.attr("data_headmark"),
                id : myData.attr("data_id"),
                reasonReject : $("#reasonForRejection").val() 
                },function callback(result){
                    window.location = "update_fabrication_qc_pass.php";
                });

        });
```

Variables that are to be passed are stored in the hidden input,

```
  echo "<input type='hidden' data_project='$row[PROJECT_NAME]' data_headmark='$row[HEAD_MARK]' data_id='$row[ID]' id='data_field'></input>";
```

So the problem is, all the buttons only work with the (#rejectButton). So even if I click accept button, only the action in the rejectClass.php are applied to the database. It supposed to be when user click acceptButton, actions in the acceptClass.php that are applied.

Please help me, im so confused.

Comment: Both functions when called result in the same callback function.  Have you checked server calls?  Have you traced as calls are made?  Have you checked the formatting/structure of your code (it's incomplete and poorly-formatted above).

Comment: I think everything works fine. I was assuming there is something wrong with the trace in the jQuery section. I don't know whats wrong why all the action goes to the rejectClass

Comment: If that's what you assume, then why haven't you provided a trace or any other analysis?  How do you know it goes to the rejectClass?

Comment: i could get the callback trace thank you so much